# Updating computed fields in Lightswitch

Tags: lightswitch-2013

How can I update computed field value programmatically without refreshing screen? When _Compute method is executed?

Comment: are you using the HTML Client or the Desktop Client?

Comment: Desktop, but what is the difference?

Comment: computed properties currently cannot be displayed on the HTML Client where as they can on the Desktop Client...

Answer (score 0):

not a tested solution but based on the HTML Client and how that works, a solution  to add a save button that updates a value

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
entity.ComputedProperty = entity.value1 + entity.value2;
}
```

tested HTML method:

```
myapp.AddEditTest.Save_execute = function (screen) {

var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var StartDate = screen.Test.StartDate;
var EndDate = screen.Test.EndDate;

screen.Days = Math.round(Math.abs((Start.getTime() - End.getTime()) / (oneDay)));

}
```

screen.Days is the Data Item I have added on the screen which acts like a computed property. running this on a save button updates and displays this value for me.